# How to use a DataGridView with a custom class and displaying a CheckBox

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

Here is my code:

```
class SelectionTableEntry
{
    public CheckBox cbIsChecked { get; set; }

    public Table Table { get; set; }

    public string TableName { get; set; }

    public Button btnEditFilter { get; set; }

    public SelectionTableEntry(Table table, bool IsChecked)
    {
        this.Table = table;
        this.TableName = table.Name;
        this.cbIsChecked = new CheckBox();
        this.cbIsChecked.Checked = IsChecked;
        this.btnEditFilter = new Button();
        this.btnEditFilter.Text = "Open";
    }
}

List<SelectionTableEntry> myList = new List<SelectionTableEntry>();

// after filling the list with items
myDataGridView.DataSource = myList;
```

Now I wanted to use a List with the type of SelectionTableEntry as a DataSource for my DataGridView.
The problem is, that the CheckBox and the Button are not displayed, so the field is empty.

How can I solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Please provide code showing how you display the button and checkbox.  Its hard to tell if these controls are even added to the DataGridView.  If I read your statement correctly, you sound as if you are merely using it in the data source which doesn't work.  A data source is for data.  You will need to add those controls to the appropriate controls collection yourself.  Did you intend to add those controls to the given table?  If so, I don't see that.

Comment: I don't know how to display the controls in the DataGridView, that's why I asked for a possible solution. How can I display them in the DataGridView?

Comment: The standard was of doing this is to have boolean property instead of Checkbox and add a column of type DataGridViewButtonColumn. Are you aware of this way of doing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGridView` has out of the box column types for checkboxes and for buttons, the [`DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.aspx) and the [`DataGridViewButtonColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.aspx).

You will automatically get a check box column for each boolean property on your DataSource object if you have AutoGenerateColumns set to true.

So your class would look like:

```
class SelectionTableEntry
{
    public bool cbIsChecked { get; set; }    
    public Table Table { get; set; }    
    public string TableName { get; set; }    
    public string btnEditFilter { get; set; }

    public SelectionTableEntry(Table table, bool IsChecked)
    {
        this.Table = table;
        this.TableName = table.Name;
        this.cbIsChecked = IsChecked;
    }
}
```

You cannot auto generate button columns, you need to add them yourself like so:

```
// Add a button column. 
DataGridViewButtonColumn buttonColumn = 
    new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
buttonColumn.HeaderText = "";
buttonColumn.Name = "Open";
buttonColumn.Text = "Open";
buttonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(buttonColumn);
```

You need to do a little bit more to react to the button clicks, but that is all explained in the MSDN article.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple tutorial on [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28VS.80%29.aspx).  It's a little dated, but I believe provides an excellent starting point when working with the DataGridView.  It may appear to be a little intimidating though - you will be required to implement your own `DataGridViewColumn` and `DataGridViewCell`.